# F# printfn "%A" to clipboard

Tags: .net, f#

How can I print any object into system clipboard just like `printfn "%A"` does?
it seems I cannot simply using `clipboard.setdataobject()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `spritnf` function, which has the same formatting capabilities as `printf` but returns the formatted string as the result. To store the string in the clipboard once you have it, you can use the `SetText` method (you'll need a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`):

```
open System.Windows.Forms

let what = [1;2;3]
let str = sprintf "%A" what
Clipboard.SetText(str)
```

After running this code, the clipboard should contain a nicely formatted F# list "[1; 2; 3]".

Comment: thanks. this is very neat. if I want to quickly copy data into excel in fsi.exe, is there a better way than this?

Comment: You can use office automation (e.g. reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel) to programmatically poke data into the spreadsheet (but offhand I don't know all the details of how).

Comment: I have an example that creates Excel spreadsheet and inserts some data into it in my functional programming book in Chapter 13. You can get the source code from: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/realworldfp